# tkinter Canvas method seemilar to Text .see()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a `Canvas` full of buttons, whose ID's I store in a dictionary.
The canvas is very long, with vertical scrollbars.
There is a way to automatically position the view at a given button?

When using a `Text`, `txt.see(position)` usually works,
but I see `Canvas` has no `see`.

The only possible alternative seems to be `.focus()`, but `cv.focus(ID)` doesnt seem to do what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no ready made function to do that, but you can implement one using `yview_moveto(fraction)`, where `fraction` is the top fraction of the canvas that will be set off-screen. So, `yview_moveto(0)` displays the top of the canvas and `yview_moveto(1)` the bottom.

What we need is to compute the fraction `y/h` that will display the button identified by `iid`. `h` is the height of the content of the canvas and `y` the height at which the button is in the canvas. I computed them using the canvas bounding box:

```
def show(iid):
    bbox = canvas.bbox('all')
    h = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    y = canvas.coords(iid)[1] - bbox[1]
    canvas.yview_moveto(y/h)
```

And below is a small example, type the button ID (between 1 and 20) in the entry and click on 'Show' to shift the view to see it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(iid):
    bbox = canvas.bbox('all')
    h = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    y = canvas.coords(iid)[1] - bbox[1]
    canvas.yview_moveto(y/h)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=lambda: show(e.get())).pack()

buttons = {}

for i in range(1, 21):
    b = tk.Button(canvas, text='Button %i' % i)
    iid = canvas.create_window(0, 30*i, anchor='nw', width=70, height=30, window=b)
    buttons[iid] = b
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

root.mainloop()
```